# Responsiveness in Rows in Materializecss Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I am building a simple one-page portfolio in Materializecss.it looks good in the browser but it looks very poor in mobile when I reduce the size of the chrome.
 It looks like this in [Browser](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B75k1pht3vgSRjg0cEtJQmJLeXM).But I need to this be in [this way](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B75k1pht3vgST0JpZFRkbnpJSVE) in resposiveness with text align and prpoerly managed.

Comment: Love your drawings

Comment: Thanks ..It improved ..!!!  [Have a look](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B75k1pht3vgSVDZ6VVRpVFV5dEU) and In mobile version, It looks like  [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B75k1pht3vgSN3lGbkJ6U1J0Ukk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div class="row">
     <div class="grid-example col m6 s12">I'm a web designer</div>
     <div class="grid-example col m6 s12">I'm a web developer</div>
 </div>`

The above code(based on materialize.css) will cover half the width on any device bigger than 600px and in smaller devices, it will cover the full width.

Visit this link for more [info](http://materializecss.com/grid.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use column size classes for small/medium/large devices (http://materializecss.com/grid.html) and combine it with hide-on- classes too for achieving what you want (http://materializecss.com/helpers.html).

Keep in mind that you need your elements to be inside a row div.